# "javaee-endorsed-api-6.0" is missing

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans

Can anyone tell me about this:
 **The project uses a class library called "javaee-endorsed-api-6.0", but this class library was not found.**
I have downloaded javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar and click Resolve in netbeans 7.3, add the jar. But it can't resolve. I have searched about this a lot. but i cant find the solution.

Comment: Answered:
EJB and EAR
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146806/javaee-endorsed-api-6-0-is-missing

Comment: I solved it using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647146/2692384

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and resolved it by installing some Java Enterprise Edition resources through NetBeans. Go to Plugins and accept to install the plugin named "EJB and EAR". Once that's done installing NetBeans will automatically find the files it needs.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add this as a **Library** (and not jar). Create a Library with the same name i.e. **javaee-endorsed-api-6.0** and **add the downloaded javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar file into this Library**. This will Resolve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve the problem by editing the file `build.properties` which is found in the IDE's userdir.
For Example on typical windows installation the file is located at `C:\Users\Kuldeep\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4`

Edit the file and add the following line:

```
libs.javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.classpath=C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 7.4\\enterprise\\modules\\ext\\javaee-api-6.0.jar
libs.javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.maven-pom=
libs.javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.src=
```

Answer (score 1):

This resolved my similar issue

1. Download this jar

   ```
   javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar
   ```

   Ensure you copy the jar file to the

   ```
   netbeans/enterprise/modules/ext directory
   ```
2. Click resolve on netbeans prompt
3. On the Netbeans ANT library manager create a new Library

   ```
   javaee-endorsed-api-6.0
   ```
4. Under classpath tab click on add JAR button and select the location in step 1

Once added you can restart netbeans and the issue is no more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's related to a missing plugin - does [this](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic21379.html) help?

Comment: Installing the EJB plug-in from NetBeans->Tools->Plugin doesn't solve the problem for me with NetBeans 7.3

Comment: @dendini . Thanks this fixed my problem

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. Got it resolved by adding library as below:

1. Click on Resolve, a window will popup.
2. It shows Class Libraries. Under it, add the library with same name as of indicated missing library, eg. for missing **javaee-endorsed-api-6.0** library file, add new library with the name **javaee-endorsed-api-6.0**
3. Once new library is added, add the necessary jar file(s) under that library by clicking Add JAR/Folder button.
4. Click OK to resolve.

**Note:-** `javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar` file is the library which, in case not present needs be downloaded and referenced for this issue.