# The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'm using Eclipse Indigo (3.7) to build an application using `ant` and a `build.xml` file.

I am getting the following exception:

```
C:\navigator\nbproject\build-impl.xml:774: The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up.
This property must point to 
org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar file which is part
of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at 
<netbeans_installation>/java<version>/ant/extra folder.
Either open the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library
exists or setup the property manually. For example like this:
 ant -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=a/path/to/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
```

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: That's not an exception, it is a custom error message. Please set the property `libs.CopyLibs.classpath`

Comment: You should copy the jar into your project's lib folder and point the `libs.CopyLibs.classpath` property (maybe in project.properties) to the jar. The jar exists in a Netbeans installation.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem after pulling a NetBeans project from GitHub. The problem was, the file `/nbproject/private.properties` contained a line...

```
"user.properties.file=C:\\Users\\Thilina\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\7.3\\build.properties"
```

...which was pointing to a wrong location. I corrected that and the problem went away.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the original question but the user user3588496 seems to be inquiring about Eclipse Indigo not Netbeans. I am experiencing the same (Eclipse) issue but I don't have Netbeans installed on my machines. So your suggestion doesn't seem to be applicable to Eclipse users.

Comment: yes, user3588496 uses eclipse. but the problem is, the project he/she trying to run is a netbeans projet. that's why it has a nbproject folder.

Comment: This also fixed `javaee-endorsed-api-6.0 is missing` for me

Answer (score 7):

**Please find below for the Solution:**
Below is an error that I was facing while building the project:

"The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up. This property must point to  org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar file which is part of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at  /java/ant/extra folder. Either open the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library exists or setup the property manually. For example like this:  ant -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=a/path/to/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar"

**Here is a solution:**

--> Open Netbeans

--> Select Project

--> Right Click

--> Property

--> Libraries

Now change the path of the library where your **javaee-endorsed-api-7.0** is stored.
In file browser

--> Select your project

--> Select lib folder

--> Click Open Button

You will ables to see it will be like: **lib\nblibraries.properties**

Now your problem is resolved.
Do not need to download the file beacuse it comes with Netbeans Package.
You just have to find the file.

[Please check image how it looks (**Project-->Libraries** & **Path**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljfBd.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

This following worked for me:

1) Downloaded and added the **org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar** to my Ant/lib directory: **C:/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib/**

2) (in command line) Navigated to the folder containing my "build.xml" file:

**cd C:\eclipse_workspace\myproject\abcfolder**

(my build.xml location: C:\eclipse_workspace\myproject\abcfolder\build.xml)

3) Ran the following commmand:

**ant -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=C:/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar**

I got a successful build.

Comment: This is a good way to brute force libs.CopyLibs.classpath when the magical IDE tools aren't populating it.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbed across this article which helped me:

[How to fix the libs](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_fix_the_libs)

Instructions for Netbeans 8

Open:

> Tools -> Options -> Java -> Ant

Paste the following in Properties:

> libs.CopyLibs.classpath=[Netbeans Install]NetBeans6.5java2antextraorg-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar

Comment: If you then get the following error:
Could not load definitions from resource org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/copylibstask/antlib.xml

You simply add the following JAR in the same tab: org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar 

I found the solution with detailed instructions here: https://vigneshravi35.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/deploy-issue-on-netbeans-antlib-xml-could-not-be-found/

Answer (score 1):

1. In NetBeans, select Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Ant
2. In the Properties section, add the following property

libs.CopyLibs.classpath=pathtoyour_netbeans/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP was asking about Eclipse, but I've run into this problem a few times using NetBeans, and the standard answer to set libs.CopyLibs.classpath property in Tools, Options, Java Properties never worked for me.  Neither has the answer that includes commenting out lines in nbproject/private/private.properties, etc.

I did find that in the Project Properties dialog, under Libraries you can create a Libraries Folder and everything you specify, including the CopyLibs jar will go in there.  I've done this to include all resources needed by a WAR file so the WAR wasn't dependent on server files and it worked for me.

Hope this helps someone looking for a NetBeans answer (maybe there is something similar in Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

It took a while before I succeeded on my mac, but using locate on the terminal gave me the correct path:
`/Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 12.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar`

That I entered into the: **NetBeans** > **Preferences** > **Java** > **Ant** > **Options** > **Properties** setting.

`libs.CopyLibs.classpath=Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 12.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks, @Liam Townsley for this editing - I will use that format next time

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, simply restarting Netbeans worked. The paths were regenerated, with the correct value.