# Failed Ant build - The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ant

I am trying to create a .war file from a svn source code that appears to be built using NetBeans.

I am aware of the question [The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532966/the-libs-copylibs-classpath-property-is-not-set-up)

However, I would like to provide further details about my setup and the answers in the other question don't resolve my issue.

I am using Eclipse Luna & Ant version apache-ant-1.9.4. Could someone please enlightenment me whether I actually need the file and if so why?  I downloaded the missing jar and the title of the jar is "org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar" which suggests to me that this jar is IDE-specific. Just making an assumption here.

Here's my error message that I receive in a command prompt on running "ant" command.

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\eclipse_workspace\MyProject\xyz\project\build-impl.xml:476: 
>   The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not This property must point to org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar file which is part
>   of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at /java/ant/extra folder.
>   Either open the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library 
>   exists or setup the property manually. For example like this: 
>    ant -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=a/path/to/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar

I can see that message is coming from my "build-impl.xml" file. But I don't really understand the purpose of the file and how to resolve this issue since I don't even have Netbeans installed on my machine.

```
        <target name="-init-taskdefs">
            <fail unless="libs.CopyLibs.classpath">
               The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up.
               This property must point to  org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar 
               file which is part of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at 
               &lt;netbeans_installation&gt;/java&lt;version&gt;/ant/extra folder.
               Either open the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library exists or setup the 
               property manually. For example like this:
               ant -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=a/path/to/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
            </fail>
            <taskdef classpath="${libs.CopyLibs.classpath}" 
            resource="org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/copylibstask/antlib.xml"/>
        </target>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to find a working solution for my situation.

1) Downloaded and added the org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar to my Ant/lib directory: **C:/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib/**

2) (in command line) Navigated to the folder containing my "build.xml" file, so it would be "abcfolder"
**C:\eclipse_workspace\myproject\abcfolder**\build.xml

3) Ran the following commmand 
**ant -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=C:/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar**

I got a successful build.

Answer (score 2):

Using NetBeans, You can resolve this problem using  these steps:

In NetBeans, select `Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Ant`.

In the `Properties` section, add the following property:

```
libs.CopyLibs.classpath=/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
```

`/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar` 
must be your `org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar` file path

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/6tU9oKF.png Hmm I don't have an "Ant" tab in Options > Miscellaneous on NetBeans 11

Comment: Please  check  with  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934617/how-can-i-find-the-ant-version-used-in-netbeans

Answer (score 2):

simply only a call of the netbeans frequently updates (Help --> Check for Updates) solved this problem on my PC (using NetBeans 8.0.2)

Answer (score 2):

checked for updates in netbeans(Help --> Check for Updates) and the problem got solved. This solved my problem......
Earlier i was thinking to re-install netbeans, but being a lenghty process I decided to search for the solution and luckily found the solution.
Guys every prob has a solution, try to get the solution in your way.....

Comment: This worked for me :) Make sure to restart Netbeans

Answer (score 2):

I updated the build.xml file and it worked

```
<target name="-init-taskdefs">
<property name="libs.CopyLibs.classpath" value="(path of netbeans 
folder)/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar"/>
<fail unless="libs.CopyLibs.classpath">
```

thank you, for referring this

Answer (score 0):

If you get "

> Could not load definitions from resource
>   org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/copylibstask/antlib.xml. It
>   could not be found.

" this error after setting Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Ant in the Properties , adding property-

```
libs.CopyLibs.classpath=/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
```

Then add jar in the upper field "Classpath" add this "org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar" jar located in your netbeans installation location inside "NetBeans 8.0.2\extide\ant\extra".

Answer (score 0):

For the main answer the setting in Netbeans. You may find is in  Tools > Options >  **Java** > Ant

And it may be easier to click Add Directory next to the Classpath window and navigate to the **...\java\ant\extra** to add that whole folder.