# How can I find the ant version used in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I am trying this tutorial [Spring MVC Netbeans](https://sites.google.com/site/springmvcnetbeans/step-by-step/)

I want to know what version of Ant my netbeans on windows is using.

Answer (score 2):

In Netbeans IDE 8.1 select 
Tools -> Options

In the Options popup select "Java"
Select "Ant" tab if it isn't already

You'll see this:

[image: Netbeans 8.1 popup showing Ant Version]